# Open local html file on same browser tab

Tags: api, browser, visual-foxpro

Trying to open a local HTML file created by a desktop application using ShellExec. The default behavior is it's being opened in the default browser (Chrome atm.). Is it possible to open it on the same tab instead of opening a new tab from the default browser the next ShellExec call?

```
 lcURL = SYS(5)+CURDIR()+ 'dummy.html'
ShellExecute(0,'open','chrome.exe',m.lcURL,'',1)
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the code that is being executed?

Comment: This is in VFP. Nothing really special but wanted to know if there's another option to achieve to bring up the HTML file on the same browser tab.

    lcURL = SYS(5)+CURDIR()+ 'dummy.html'
    ShellExecute(0,'open','chrome.exe',m.lcURL,'',1)